# Update context from child components on load and on update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Goal: one child should register the update from another child, then not re-render infinitely. The following is a story of no updates or infinite loops. If you are a master of hooks (or at least not an amateur like I), this is for you.

Suppose there is a single context that will hold state.

```
const TestContext = React.createContext('hello')
```

Suppose that in the main App.js file, there is a single state variable holding a complex, nested object.

```
const [testState,setTestState] = React.setState({})
```

There are multiple children that will receive the state through a Provider:

```
<TestContext.Provider value={[testState,setTestState]}>

{SomeChildrenGoHere}

</TestContext.Provider>
```

Now suppose one of those children wishes to update the context on load:

```
var TestComponentOne = function(){
    
    const [testState,setTestState] = React.useContext(TestContext)
    
    var GetTestVar(){
    
    if('testVar2' in testState){
    
        return(<h1>Success</h1>)
    
    }
    
    else{
    
        return(<h1>Not yet...</h1>)
    
    }
    
    var UpdateState = function(){
    
       setTestState({...testState,"testVar1":"testVar1"})
    
    }
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
       UpdateState()
    
    },[testState])
    
}
```

And another child component wants to do the same...

```
var TestComponentTwo = function(){
    
    const [testState,setTestState] = React.useContext(TestContext)
    
    var GetTestVar(){
    
    if('testVar1' in testState){
    
        return(<h1>Success</h1>)
    
    }
    
    else{
    
        return(<h1>Not yet...</h1>)
    
    }
    
    var UpdateState = function(){
    
        setTestState({...testState,"testVar2":"testVar2"})
    
    }
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
       UpdateState()
    
    },[testState])
    
}
```

I have tried the following useEffects however I either get zero updates (as expected with an empty array) or an infinite loop.

Permutation 1:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
           UpdateState()
        
        },[testState])
```

Permutation 2 (No reload expected):

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
           UpdateState()
        
        },[])
```

Permutation 3:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
           UpdateState()
        
        })
```

The question is: how to achieve the functionality without the infinite re-renders or lack of rendering past the initial load? The context state should be updateable from children while listening for updates from other children. Dependencies should not be hard coded other than the state object. In other words, no specific keys as dependencies.

Also should note, I've tried wrapping the useContext in a useRef.

Edit: https://playcode.io/1241366

Comment: your effects dependency arrays include state that is updated in the effecta, which will result in infinite re-renders. Correct me if I'm wrong but there is no specific question here, it just seems like you are describing and demonstrating how a useEffect hook works. If you just want to do an effect on mount then providing an empty dependency array is the solution.

Comment: @damonholden The question is how to achieve the functionality without the infinite re-renders. I'm using the hook incorrectly, however I'm not sure where the error is. What I want to do is update the context state from children while listening for updates from other children. Goal: one child should register the update from another child, then not re-render infinitely.

Comment: @damonholden I've modified the question. Also added that dependencies should not be hard coded other than the state object. In other words, no specific keys as dependencies (eg: useEffect(()=>{functionCall()},[testState["subKey"]).

Comment: When you use `useContext` you are `listening` to the children if they are inside the context. No need to use `useEffect` for that.

Comment: @programandoconro The goal of useEffect is to perform the equivalent of a componentDidMount. If the function to update the state is called outside useEffect, it throws a: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." When the component loads it should update the state, but it doesn't seem to respond to state updates from other components unless useEffect is called with a dependency. I thought it would update without useEffect  too.

Comment: @WrittenInCode I think you do not need `componentDidupdate` this is already handled by the context. If you need to run some side effects when the state updates, just do not add the setState inside the effect.

Comment: It's not being called directly. That's the error coming from React. (I guess it uses those functions under the hood for functional components?) I thought the state would be directly accessible from the provider and any calls to setTestState, passed from the provider, should update. But that's not what's happening unfortunately.

Comment: @WrittenInCode then I think you should check your code and see if you are correctly using the context. Normally it does automatically updates the state in the children. That is why it is called context. Another advice will be not to use `var` in you code, there is no justification to do it in modern js.

Comment: @programandoconro In this context (no pun intended) it's not working as intended unfortunately. If you have a playground/snack example of this situation working, that would be much appreciated. Other situations it's fine. Re: use of var - are you inferring strong vs weak typing is affecting this situation? I'm not sure how that is relevant.

Comment: @WrittenInCode the situation you are trying to explain is not clear, at least to me. Maybe you are the one that should provide a playground? Re: no, I am not inferring it is affecting using var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After better understanding your issue, your problem is not to do with context or your component effects at all. You are just simply updating state multiple times in a single render cycle in a way that results in React not storing each change.

Consider the following functions from your component tree:

```
//...

var SetState = function () {
    setTestData({
        ...testData,

        testOne: 'Hello from Test One',
    });
};

//...

var SetState = function () {
    setTestData({
        ...testData,

        testTwo: 'Hello from Test Two',
    });
};

//...
```

When your app renders and your component effects are executed, React will process the previous two functions in the following way:

- The first `setState` function is invoked - asking React to que a re-render and setting the `testData` state from `{}` to `{testOne: 'Hello from Test One'}` **after** the re-render.
- Later on, the second `setState` function is invoked, which you may think changes the same `testData` state to `{testOne: 'Hello from Test One', testTwo: 'Hello from Test Two'}`. However, React has not triggered a re-render yet and therefore `testData` still references `{}`, so now, after a re-render, testData **will** become `{testTwo: 'Hello from Test Two'}`.

This is why it almost seems like there is some miscommunication between your state updates, but this is expected behaviour in React. The solution is to use callbacks in your state setters so that React can use the result of each setter callback as the data for the next:

```
var SetState = function () {
    setTestData((previousState) => {
        return {
            ...previousState,
            testOne: 'Hello from Test One',
        };
    });
};

var SetState = function () {
    setTestData((previousState) => {
        return {
            ...previousState,
            testTwo: 'Hello from Test Two',
        };
    });
};
```

This behaviour of setting state in React is well documented and [you can read more about it on their official documentation, here](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state).

Comment: @programandoconro Turns out let vs var is important for assigning the object in this answer. Beautiful gents. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You are having state race condition between the 2 components. So you need to wait for one component to change the state and then change the state in the other component before the other component.

To solve it, you need to create a new state to check if the state was already updated.

I edited the [code](https://playcode.io/1241366) you shared in the comments.

```
import React from 'react';

const TestContext = React.createContext('hello');

var TestComponentOne = function () {
  const { testData, setTestData, isRendered } = React.useContext(TestContext);

  var SetState = function () {
    setTestData({
      ...testData,

      testOne: 'Hello from Test One',
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    isRendered && SetState();

    console.log(testData);
  }, [isRendered]);

  var GetState = function () {
    if (testData && 'testTwo' in testData) {
      return testData['testTwo'];
    } else {
      return 'No luck in getting the updated state from Component Two';
    }
  };

  return <p>{GetState()}</p>;
};

var TestComponentTwo = function () {
  const { testData, setTestData, setIsRendered } = React.useContext(TestContext);

  var SetState = function () {
    setTestData({
      ...testData,

      testTwo: 'Hello from Test Two',
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    SetState();
    setIsRendered(true);
    console.log(testData);
  }, []);

  var GetState = function (number) {
    if (testData && 'testOne' in testData) {
      return testData['testOne'];
    } else {
      return 'No luck in getting the updated state from Component One';
    }
  };

  return <p>{GetState()}</p>;
};

export function App(props) {
  const [testData, setTestData] = React.useState({});
  const [isRendered, setIsRendered] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value={{ testData, setTestData, isRendered, setIsRendered }}>
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello React.</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <p></p>
        <TestComponentOne />
        <TestComponentTwo />
      </div>
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console');
```

EDIT: please check @damonholden for the correct answer using callback when setting the state.

Comment: While this solution works it does not fix the problem rather than it just patches the result of the issue in a second render. Also, I'd avoid describing it as a "render competition" as it makes it seem like the result could be different but the behaviour is always consistent as per effect execution order.

Comment: @damonholden you are right! nice catch!

Comment: Gents, thanks to both of you. These answers are extremely helpful. CC: @damonholden